# Using enter to select item twitter bootstrap typeahead on firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am having a problem with firefox submitting my form when you press enter to select an item from the typeahead. Chrome and Internet Explorer work as expected where you press enter once to select the item from the typeahead then press enter again to submit. I have been able to disable pressing enter for submitting completely

```
function stopEnter(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

I would prefer to get firefox working like the other browsers.
Here is my test code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var abc = ['asd', 'bvc', 'cxz', 'dsa', 'ewq', 'fgh', 'gfd', 'hrf', 'iuuy', 'aqq', 'bvb', 'ccc'];
            $('#typer').typeahead({ source: abc }).focus();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server" >
        <asp:Panel DefaultButton="button1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox data-provide="typeahead" ID="typer" autocomplete="off" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button text="submit" ID="button1" runat="server" OnClick="button1_Click" />
            </div>
         </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(typer.Text);
}
```

It looks like when I remove the panel it can function as desired but on the real page I have this code on a master page in a modal and when you press enter it will submit a button on the original page you were on.

Comment: Use `e.which`, not `e.keyCode`

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I do not want to use that bit of code anyway.